# Using ofstream rvalue in a class to write file

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

I want to make simple class for writing csv files. I have problem with passing/using ofstream. I want class to have two contractors. One taking string and making ofstream, and second taking ofstream as argument.

This is testing code that I use now to understand what is happening but cant:

```
class Test {
public:

  Test (const string & s):of {move(ofstream(s))} {}
  Test (ofstream && s):of {move(s)} {}

  ~Test() {of.close();}

  void write(const string & s) {
    of << s << endl;
  }


private:
  ofstream && of;
};


int main()
{


  // case 1
  Test t(ofstream{"/tmp/test2.csv"});
  t.write("SDFSDF");
  t.write("SDFSDF");

  // case 2
  Test t2("/tmp/test3.csv");
  t2.write("SDFSDF");
  t2.write("SDFSDF");


  //case 3
  ofstream ofs("/tmp/test4.csv");
  Test t3(move(ofs));
  t3.write("SDFSDF");
  t3.write("SDFSDF");

   return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and executes. But in cases 1 and 2 resulting files are empty. In  the 3rd case, no file is created at all. Why? What is happening? Maybe I'm using the rvalue references in a wrong way? If so, how should I use them? Or maybe there is better way to do what I am trying to achieve and rvalues are not needed?

Answer (score 1):

In the first constructor, an ofstream is initialized. Then "move" is applied on it, which only change the return type during compile time to a r-value reference. And then the reference is used to initialize another reference "of". Then the instance is destroyed. "write" try to write into a destroyed object, which cause the error.

R-value reference is still a reference, consider it as a pointer. I think you should declare "of" as ofstream.

Comment: Thanks. I changed to `ofstream of;` but now geterrors for the first two constructors: `error: use of deleted function 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<char>&)'
   Test (const string & s):of {move(ofstream(s))} {}`. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Looking in `/usr/include/c++/4.9/fstream` on my system, GCC's library does not define a move constructor for `fstream`s, so you can't move one. Although the standard does require a move constructor... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream

Comment: Looks like they did add it upstream: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/fstream#L910-L931

Comment: @painterflap , for the first constructor, I think you can use
` Test (const string & s):of(s) {}`
I don't think a move is needed here.